# weird netstat output on netscaler

Tags: connection, netstat, netscaler

We have a VPX-1000 netscaler. When traffic suddenly increases our website goes offline and doesn't response to requests but our netscaler load is fine (cpu %40 ram %50  4 cores 4gb). After incident occurs every time when traffic increases I've decided to check connection stats. Then I simply run a netstat command and try to sort it. But it shows weird output as seen in screen capture. Could you please help me why this output seen not as expected. OR what does this output means ? Thank you.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzefC.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're sorting before adding the `uniq -c`. If you want to sort after reducing all duplicates, you should say so in your command:

```
netstat -tan | awk '{ print $6 }' | uniq -c | sort
```

This is wild guessing as you haven't stated *what* is *not expected* of the output.

Comment: weird thing is first 2 lines of the output. as their values are ok (12 and 11) but information column name is empty, and second weird thing is all the output starts with fff. Any idea what do these mean ?

Comment: You've only included the abbreviated information. That way, I can't help you as I don't know the original content. Deliver the output for `netstat -tun` without any piping afterwards so that all data will be visible. Than the "origin" of those ffffff-Entries will be obvious as well.

Comment: thank you for your help. here is the output of netstat -tun [output](https://ibb.co/i0O31m)

Comment: These are UNIX sockets and they're named perfectly fine. This has nothing to do with your load or traffic. Please read `man netstat` to only request the information that you need, especially `--ip` looks useful for you.

Comment: thank you @Stefan M but other netscaler doesn't show this output. It's perfectly simple and only show connection counts and doesn't show unix sockets. And it doesn't go offline. Only the one I've shared shows this information on netstat output and goes offline after the load increases :(